# How to deal with C++ generated symbol prefixes in shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, symbols, prefix

I have couple od classes in my shared library (.so). Everything worked good until I haven`t added new function to one of my classes. C++ compiler than gived different prefix to one of my existing function symbols, which broke loading of another application.

To explain it better, I will write small example, it is not based on real source or compiled data:

When compiling:

```
class Foo1 {
public:
  void func1();
  void func2();
}
```

compiler will generate symbols **_Ejjfunc1** and **_Ejlfunc2**. These symbols will be in shared library. I will compile and link my application which is using these functions. Then I will add new function to library:

```
class Foo1 {
public:
  void func1();
  void func11();
  void func2();
}
```

and I will compile library and get symbols **_Ejjfunc1**, **_Ejlfunc11** and **_Ejifunc2**. Loading of application linked to **_Ejlfunc2** is broken, because function has different prefix **_Eji**.

How am I supposed to deal with this situation? I understand I can not delete function, or change arguments since it is change in library interface, but adding new function should be OK therefore I don`t have to make new version of library.

Thanks for any opinion.

Comment: Use a different namespace, perhaps

Comment: Perhaps this can help:http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++#The_Do.27s_and_Don.27ts. One of the don'ts is to change the order of virtual functions (if Foo1 overrides a base's virtual functions the functions are virtual even if not declared explicitly virtual).

Comment: I guess problems like these are one of the reasons why many libraries offer only C interfaces.. Not to mention portability across compilers etc.. Unfortunately, C++ makes this very hard..

Comment: @PeterSchneider that is very usefull material. I think you should consider reference to library programming policy as an answer.